# Add search to list of categories in post editor

Tags: categories, metabox, post-editor

I have many categories in my WordPress website. Each time I am adding new post it is very hard to find specific category that I need this time.

It would be much easier if I had search field right above list of categories (Categories Metabox) when I am editing post. How can I do it? Or maybe there is some plugin for it?

[image]

For example search button can be added after "Most used" tab.

Answer (score 2):

I found this plugin called **WP Admin Category Search**

https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-category-search/

It is not looking very popular but it seems to work.